# Expect script to give multiple inputs

Tags: expect

I want to ssh to list of servers and set a unique value on the each server using expect script.

Example:
I've 10 servers. server1 to 10
I've asset tag of the server assettag1 to 10.
I want to ssh to each server and update the asset tag value on each server.

Thanks,
Sukumar

Comment: My exact requirement is like this.

I've a Dell Chassis of 16 blades. I want to login to each idrac management console and update  on of the value in the server which is unique.

Comment: What have you written so far, and what problem(s) do you have with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script that may help you.
As you can see the values are passed as arguments to **myscript.sh** where the *expect* code is located.

```
#!/bin/bash
adresses=("192.168.1.1" "192.168.1.2" "192.168.1.3" "192.168.1.4" "192.168.1.5" "192.168.1.6" "192.168.1.7")
hostnames=("ap02" "ap03" "ap04" "ap05" "ap06" "ap07" "ap08")

### Main ###
for cpt in {0..6}
do
        ./myscript.sh ${adresses[${cpt}]} ${hostnames[${cpt}]}
        cpt=$(( $cpt +1 ))
done
```

Here is how I use the arguments in **myscript.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set ipaddr [lindex $argv 0];
set hostname [lindex $argv 1];
...
```

Where `$argv` 0 is the first argument and `$argv 1` the second